# How to make mocha watch, compile and test coffeescript with dependencies on save

Tags: unit-testing, node.js, tdd, coffeescript, mocha.js

I'm working on a project that uses coffeescript for development and testing. I run the tests in node with mocha's --watch flag on so I can have the tests run automatically when I make changes.

While this works to some extent, only the ./test/test.*.coffee files are recompiled when something is saved. This is my directory structure:

```
/src/coffee
-- # Dev files go here
/test/
-- # Test files go here
```

The mocha watcher responds to file changes inside the /src and /test directories, but as long as only the files in the /test directory are recompiled continuous testing is kind of borked. If I quit and restart the watcher process the source files are also recompiled. How can I make mocha have the coffee compiler run over the development files listed as dependencies inside the test files on each run?

Comment: Seems like you need a build tool. Take a look at [flour](http://github.com/ricardobeat/cake-flour) or [grunt](http://gruntjs.com)

Comment: Thanks. Tried Grunt with simplemocha, but I'm getting generic JS errors with simplemocha. Gonna try flour now.

Comment: I am writing an anwser based on grunt.js, it's easily doable but I am not sure how you compile your files to js and if you run your tests in js or coffee.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answers! Is it possible to do this using just a Makefile?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is my answer using grunt.js

You will have to install grunt and few additionnal packges.

```
npm install grunt grunt-contrib-coffee grunt-simple-mocha grunt-contrib-watch
```

And write this grunt.js file:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-coffee');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-simple-mocha');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

  grunt.initConfig({
    coffee:{
      dev:{
        files:{
          'src/*.js':'src/coffee/*.coffee',
        }
      },
      test:{
        files:{          
          'test/test.*.js':'test/test.*.coffee'
        }
      }
    },
    simplemocha:{
      dev:{
        src:"test/test.js",
        options:{
          reporter: 'spec',
          slow: 200,
          timeout: 1000
        }
      }
    },
    watch:{
      all:{
        files:['src/coffee/*', 'test/*.coffee'],
        tasks:['buildDev', 'buildTest', 'test']
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('test', 'simplemocha:dev');
  grunt.registerTask('buildDev', 'coffee:dev');
  grunt.registerTask('buildTest', 'coffee:test');
  grunt.registerTask('watch', ['buildDev', 'buildTest', 'test', 'watch:all']);

};
```

Note: I didn't have some detials on how you build / run your tests so you certainly have to addapt ;)

Then run the grunt watch task :

```
$>grunt watch
```

Comment: There may be a problem when installing grunt-simple-mocha, it already using grunt v0.4 of grunt and npm currently still have v0.3 of it. So i checked out v0.2 of grunt-simple-mocha to make it work with old grunt from npm

Answer (score 3):

Using a Cakefile with [flour](http://github.com/ricardobeat/cake-flour):

```
flour = require 'flour'
cp    = require 'child_process'

task 'build', ->
    bundle 'src/coffee/*.coffee', 'lib/project.js'

task 'watch', ->
    invoke 'build'
    watch 'src/coffee/', -> invoke 'build'

task 'test', ->
    invoke 'watch'
    cp.spawn 'mocha --watch', [], {stdio: 'inherit'}
```

Mocha already watches the `test/` folder, so you only need to watch `src/`.